# HTML "iFrame" using same "src"

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, iframe, eclipse-rcp

I produced a manual for my Eclipse RCP application using Eclipse help system. 
I would like to export this documentation as a browsable offline html documentation. 
To do so, I used Eclipse export function from Help System at runtime which produced a plain HTML file with table of content in the top of the document.

My question is, is there an automatic way of separating the table of contents and the contents itself?

Example, specifying an Iframe that use this single document and specify src attribute from the beginning of the document to the end of the table of contents, and a second Iframe with same plain html document as src but which would begin at the beginning of the contents.

For instance, using two iframes, the left hand one for the table of contents and the right hand one for the contents.

I could do it manually or implement a parser using jdom but if you know a better solution...

I also thought about enclosing the whole HTML document with a table with a single row and two columns, one for the table of contents and one for the contents but the bad point is that when selecting an entry in the table of contents, both "sides" will scroll I think. I would like the two parts to be decorrelated, fixed table of contents with a vertical slider if needed and contents in the right part.

Best regards,

Christophe.